# Refresh datatable with ajax after adding new entry

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I'd like to refresh a  dynamically when new Elements has been created.
I came around 3 solutions, and like to know which is best and to prefer.
Or rather: I like nr. 3 (ajax) most, but unfortunatelly this is the one not working. And I wonder how I could make it work.

a). with @Observes:

public class Facade {

```
private List<Customer> customerList;

public void createNew() {
    service.create(newCustomer);
    event.fire(newCustomer);
}

public void onCustomerChanged(
        @Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS) final Customer newCustomer) {
    findAll();
}

@PostConstruct
public void findAll() {
    customerList = service.findByNamedQuery("Customer.ALL");
}

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
}
```

}

b). just call the findAll update method directly in the dontect of createNew:

```
    public void createNew() {
        service.create(newCustomer);
        findAll();
    }
```

c). with Ajax:

```
    public void createNew() {
        service.create(newCustomer);
    }


    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton id="register" action="#{facade.createNew()}"
            value="Register">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":customerTable" />
            </h:commandBUtton>
    </h:form>

<h:datatable id="customerTable" var="_customer" value="facade.customerList">
```

Unfortunatelly the ajax thing does work delayed: eg create customer1 > nothing happens. create cust2 > datatable refreshes and displays cust1. and so on.

How could I fix that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the list after adding new entry, exactly as you did in b).